# C# Visual Studio "The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\404 Masaüstü Uygulaması.exe' because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a windows form application (.net framework) that was running without an error when the project had only 1 form.
When I added another form to my project and in the code I added the code to switch to other form I get this error:

I looked in Task Manager and I couldn't find any Form Application.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgkVM.png)

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q84WR.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the application is running. Restart VS.

Comment: Unfortunately... There is no form_application in tast manager. And also when I restart VS I get this error again.

Comment: When I looked task manager in detail . I saw another form-application application that has another icon . When I closed it and restart VS . The problem is solved thank you.